# Newtonsoft JSON.NET and spaces in json key bug?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Take the following valid json:

```
{
   "universe": {
      "solar system": "sun"
   }
}
```

and here's the simple C# code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
JToken x = JToken.Parse("{\"universe\": {\"solar system\": \"sun\"}}");
string s = x.First.First.First.Path;
```

At this point `s = "universe['solar system']"`

However I'm expecting `"universe.['solar system']"` (notice the '.' after "universe").

If the json key does not have a space ("solar_system") I get `"universe.solar_system"` which is correct.

The question is: Is this a bug in json.net or do I need to do something else to support spaces in json keys?

Thanks,

PT

Comment: no, key is the object and you can't define object with space

Comment: AFAIK not a bug, just that bracket notation is mandatory when accessing a key with a space. Can't find any supporting documentation at the moment hence a comment only.

Comment: Well, any json validators will happily validate jsons with spaces in the keys including Newtonsoft's json.net which wraps them withing square brackets.  My problem is the missing dot '.' between the keys.

Comment: The path is intended to be in [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) syntax, which supports both dot-notation like `$.store.book[0].title` as well as bracket–notation like `$['store']['book'][0]['title']`.  So `universe['solar system']` is perfectly valid, and if you pass it to [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) you'll get the correct value `"sun"`.

Comment: @dbc I believe this is the answer to the question.  Its not a bug, its intended.  You should post this as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug.  The path returned by [`JToken.Path`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm) is intended to be in [JSONPath syntax](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).  As explained in the [original JSONPath proposal](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):

> JSONPath expressions can use the *dot*–notation
>
> `$.store.book[0].title`
>
> or the *bracket*–notation
>
> `$['store']['book'][0]['title']`

So `universe['solar system']` is perfectly valid, and if you pass it to [`SelectToken()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm) you'll get the correct value `"sun"` back:

```
JToken x = JToken.Parse("{\"universe\": {\"solar system\": \"sun\"}}");
string path = x.First.First.First.Path;

Console.WriteLine(path);    // Prints universe['solar system']
var val = (string)x.SelectToken(path);
Console.WriteLine(val);     // Prints "sun"
Debug.Assert(val == "sun"); // No assert
```

See also [Querying JSON with SelectToken and escaped properties](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm).

If you nevertheless want the extra `.` in the path you can create your own extension method `JTokenExtensions.ExpandedPath(this JToken token)` based on the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L184).

Comment: Thanks much for the help.